# docker instance of masterless salt showing folders of my system

Tags: docker, dockerfile, salt-stack, docker-machine

When I start a docker instance of **masterless saltstack**, and I do ***cd srv/salt*** followed by ***ls***, it it shows all folder in my system, but docker should create a machine instance of its own and not have any folders of my actual machine.
I used this docker image https://hub.docker.com/r/enonic/docker-salt-masterless-ubuntu/ .
Please help.
[This is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pxxhu.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the command you're using to start up the containter?

If you're following the instructions on https://hub.docker.com/r/enonic/docker-salt-masterless-ubuntu/ then it's going to mount your current working directory to `/srv/salt` in the container.

Comment: I want to run salt in masterless mode in docker.
And yes, I did use those instructions. 
What should the procedure be for running masterless salt in docker?
"docker run enonic/docker-salt-masterless-ubuntu"...will this work?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are in /srv/salt and its mounting "$(pwd):/srv/salt". 
enter code hereyou can change it as per your retirement eg:-

"/opt/salt/:/srv/salt" or "your location:/srv/salt"

/srv/salt is compulsory